# Draw an arrow in racket

Tags: scheme, racket, pict

How to draw an arrow in a frame in racket (DrRacket)? For example between two objects: a circle and a rectangle obtained by:

```
(send dc draw-ellipse 50 50 30 30) and (send dc draw-rectangle 200 200 30 6)
```

Comment: Depending on the goal of the program, it might be easier to draw a `pict` and then send the pict to the frame as a bitmap because it would avoid all the message passing semantics. `pict` is also easier to use in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can use picts to do such things.

First, you define your picts.

```
(define pict-a (rectangle 40 40))

(define pict-b (circle 40))
```

Then you combine them to be able to use rc-find or lc-find, which are the procedures that will help you connect those picts.

```
(define combined (hc-append 200 pict-a pict-b))
```

Finally

```
> (pin-arrows-line 30 combined
                   pict-a rc-find
                   pict-b lc-find
                   #:start-angle (/ pi 11)
                   #:end-angle (- (/ pi 11))
                   #:solid? #f)
```

Will produce this:
[image: Two picts connected]

You can find more information in [the docs!](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/Basic_Pict_Constructors.html?q=arrow) Tell us if that solved your problem!

Comment: I agree with you. But I want to do the same on a frame (GUI). It's possible?

Comment: I'm not used to GUI with Racket but I'm pretty sure you can send pics to a frame (?) and display it.

Comment: Can you try please David?

Comment: As I said I'm not used to GUI with Racket, I've never done it before, but since Racket uses Lambda programming you can pass a function to generate the pict and display it later.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of arrows?

- For simple arrows use [`draw-line`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/dc___.html?q=draw-line#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._racket%2Fdraw..rkt%29._dc~3c~25~3e%29._draw-line%29%29) directly.
- For bended arrows use [`draw-spline`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/dc___.html?q=draw-spline#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._racket%2Fdraw..rkt%29._dc~3c~25~3e%29._draw-spline%29%29).
  Use a filled triangle as a simple arrow head.

If you need a prettier arrow head shape, 
one option is to adapt the [arrow shape](https://github.com/soegaard/metapict/blob/master/metapict/arrow.rkt) from [MetaPict](http://soegaard.github.io/docs/metapict/metapict.html).

You can find other examples of arrows in MetaPict's documentation.

An example with a [non-straight arrow](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-December/065039.html) which shows how to draw a state machine with MetaPict.

Comment: An arrow as in oriented graphs or Petri nets to connect two nodes. A bit like too pin-line-arrow but in frame.